# How Can I Pass Recipient to Email in sharesheet when user clicks EMAIL ITEM without using mfmailcomposer

Tags: ios, swift

I am using share sheet for sharing files through mail,whatsapp etc.i want to set default email recipient(To Address).I was tried a lot I can able to set Subject for mail but I am not able to set recipient.its necessary for my app.(In stack over flow showing there is no option to set to sddress).if its not there in share sheet let me know when user clicks share sheet items how can I detect and do operation.please help me

I am excepting when user clicks share sheet item for example mail for that I have to set To Address(recipient).(WITH OUT USING MFMAILCOMPOSER)

Comment: my requirement is without using MFMailComposeViewController.Because that is direct action and that is only for mail.i want to give recipient when mail item clicks in share sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
let mailer = MFMailComposeViewController()
mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self
mailer.setSubject("")
let toRecipients = ["recipient mail ID"]
mailer.setToRecipients(toRecipients as? [String])
let emailBody = ""
mailer.setMessageBody(emailBody, isHTML: false)
mailer.navigationBar.barStyle = .blackOpaque
present(mailer, animated: true)
```

Comment: My requirement is when user clicks button share , the iOS default share sheet appear(For this I was used ActivityviewController) .in That share if mail clicks I want to detect what user clicks or set recipient to Activity view Controller.   I am using this         let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: filesToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.setValue("Database", forKey: "Subject")